# Установка Drupal 7, ошибка соединения с свервером базы данных

Tags: mysql, drupal, vps

При установке Drupal 7 столкнулся с проблемой.

> `Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES).`

Вот линк на скрин

[image]

ПС. Устанавливаю на виртуальный сервер.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Установка Drupal 7: failed to connect to your database server](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/342934/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-drupal-7-failed-to-connect-to-your-database-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

База данных "drupal" - создана? Какой пароль? По умолчанию, если юзера не создавали, то юзер - 'root' и пароля нет или вписывайте юзера и пароль. А MySQL - вообще запущен?

Comment: ну тут шаманов нет однозначно,что за ошибка? где лог? и это точно,однозначно,решать не здесь а на руткоде!
имхо - лучше в Debian поставить виртуалку и накатить винду,чем наоборот,вы собираетесь быть программистом или что-бы с "шашечками"?
По мэйн вопросу -решили? База - отвечает?

Comment: Спасибо. Со всем разобрался) программистом