# Установка Drupal 7: failed to connect to your database server

Tags: php, drupal

При установке Drupal 7 столкнулся с проблемой.

> Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Вот линк на скрин

[image]

ПС. Устанавливаю на виртуальный сервер.

Comment: Опишите, как вы настроили базу данных: пользователь, название базы. Возможно, вы просто не настроили БД.

Comment: @Сяськаа, так чем закончилось-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в общем-то все просто... Drupal говорит вам, что не смог подключиться к указанной вами базе по указанному вами адресу с указанными вами учетными данными по причине того, что пользователю admin хоста localhoct запрещен доступ.

Хотелось бы предварительно уточнить... К базе подключиться пробовали? Это в принципе возможно? Ну, типа, из shell или через phpMyAdmin? Пользователь admin в MySQL заведен, или только пост-установочный root? А root-ом подключиться пробовали?

Одним словом - присоединяюсь к [[@Ilya Makarov](/users/1284/ilya-makarov)](http://admin.hashcode.ru/users/1284/ilya-makarov). Подробности виртуалки в общем и базы в частности - в студию!

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что да, в MySQL есть у вас юзер admin с неизвестным паролем. А что, при установке об этом не спрашивали? Я бы в таком случае **переименовал** бы все конфиги, относящиеся к этому делу (переименовал бы - чтобы в случае чего можно было вернуть обратно), и запустил заново!